# Occasional empty folders in Object Explorer tree in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: windows-11, ssms, ms-sql

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2022 Express and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 19.1 on a fresh Windows 11 Pro installation.

From time to time, after connecting to my localhost\SQLEXPRESS server in Management Studio, I don't see any objects in Object Explorer tree (for example I can see the Databases folder, but it's empty inside). There are no any visible errors and I can still see the databases in available databases dropdown list above the object explorer and use them.

Reconnecting to the database doesn't help. Application restart is needed to possibly get rid of the problem.

The whole situation is totally random. I can't see any patterns and it seems that the probability of the issue is something like 10%.

Also, from time to time there's an error dialog shown on application startup:

*Unable to process the existing user settings and will overwrite the file with user settings from this session*

How can I try to diagnoze this? Where do I start?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that my CPU was the culprit. Its third core turned to be degraded and was failing when going over 5500Mhz because of turbo boost that allows to clock one or two cores to 5800Mhz when conditions are met (using default BIOS setup, no XMP, no OC and no undervolting).

I tried to run SSMS on different cores (using task manager and process affinity settings) to diagnose the issues and that's how I found that core #2 is a problem.

I've limited the turbo boost to 5500Mhz globally and the issues are gone.